# How to run a meteor app in docker on mac?

Tags: macos, meteor, docker

I am trying to run a meteor app in a docker container on my mac using the meteord base image, but getting a

```
=> You don't have an meteor app to run in this image.
```

error message when

```
$ docker run -it -e ROOT_URL=http://localhost -e MONGO_URL=mongodb://192.168.99.101:27017/meteor -v /Users/me/build/bundle -p 8080:80 meteorhacks/meteord:base
```

I built the meteor bundle by

```
$ meteor build --architecture=os.linux.x86_64 ./
```

Can I use meteord on the mac?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in [`base/scripts/run_app.sh#L3-L21`](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteord/blob/f73853609884179c5f199ba1d381c4e2224ba58f/base/scripts/run_app.sh#L3-L21), that error message pops up when there is no `/bundle`, `$BUNDLE_URL` or `/build_app` path in the container.

And `-v /Users/me/build/bundle` isn't enough to declare a `/bundle` path in the container: you need to [map it (mount a host directory)](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume):

```
-v /Users/me/build/bundle:/bundle
```

`-v /Users/me/build/bundle` alone declares a [data volume](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#adding-a-data-volume), it doesn't mount anything from the host.